# Unable to find the appium path

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WedDriverAgent

After using the command in terminal :

install appium and try to find the path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WedDriverAgent

Expected: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium  path alone displaying
Remianing are not there